# Pointer as parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

[image]

The code doesn't work in my Xcode compiler. It says *&point expected '('. I really don't know what goes wrong. It should have worked.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void transformCopy(int *point);
void transformTrue(int *&point);

int main(){

    int *a,*b,i=0;

    transformTrue(a);
    transformCopy(b);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {a[i]=i;}
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){printf("%d  ",a[i]);}
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {b[i]=i;}
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){printf("%d  ",b[i]);}
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
void transformCopy(int *point){
    point=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
}
void transformTrue(int *&point){
    point=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *&point expected '('.

References do not exist in C ( `void transformTrue(int *&point)` ), this is C++ code, not C

If you want to have the equivalent in C you have to use `void transformTrue(int **point)` and you have to call `transformTrue(&a);`

---

If I change your code to do in C what it is done in C++ (see comments) :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void transformCopy(int *point);
void transformTrue(int ** point); /* ** rather than *& */

int main(){

    int *a,*b = 0,i=0;

    transformTrue(&a); /* &a rather than just a */
    transformCopy(b);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {a[i]=i;}
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){printf("%d  ",a[i]);}
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {b[i]=i;}
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){printf("%d  ",b[i]);}
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
void transformCopy(int *point){
    point=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
}
void transformTrue(int ** point){ /* ** rather than *& */
    *point=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int)); /* *point = rather than point = */
}
```

`transformTrue(&a)` modifies the value of *a*, but `transformCopy(b);` does nothing except locally (and a memory leak)  and back in *main* the value of *b* is still 0, the program will crash when you will try to write in invalid addresses

one possibility is to change *transformCopy* like that :

```
int * transformCopy(){
  return (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
}
```

and of course the call to have `b = transformCopy();`

Comment: @Liu I did, reread my answer (I edited it previously). Note that in your code thare are other 'strange' things, in _transformCopy_ the malloc is lost because you modify only the value of the parameter without any impact on the caller

Comment: thanks a lot!  So you mean the reference like *& and &* never exist in C??